# How to display the maximum value in sql with 2 categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this at the moment:

**Table siswa:**

```
create table siswa(nis char(4) primary key, nama char(20), jk char(1), tmpt_lahir char(10), tgl_lahir date, nm_wali char(20), alamat char(50));
```

**Insert Into table siswa:**

```
insert into siswa values('0001', 'budi', 'L', 'sekayu', '1994-05-30', 'yanto', 'kayuara'), ('0002', 'joko', 'L', 'lumpatan', '1995-05-28', 'usman', 'bailangu'), ('0003', 'santoso', 'L', 'kayuara', '1994-05-30', 'yanto', 'kayuara'), ('0004', 'susan', 'P', 'bailangu', '1995-03-02', 'michael', 'bailangu'), ('0005', 'marta', 'L', 'epil', '1995-05-07', 'yanto', 'sekayu'), ('0006', 'lusi', 'P', 'sekayu', '1995-03-02', 'budi', 'lumpatan'), ('0007', 'manap', 'L', 'lumpatan', '1995-05-28', 'abdul', 'kayuara'), ('0008', 'budi', 'L', 'kayuara', '1994-12-01', 'subhan', 'kayuara');
```

**Table mata_pljran**

```
create table mata_pljran(kd_mp char(10) primary key, nm_mp char(20), kelas char(2), semester char(10), kkm int);
```

**Insert into table mata_pljran**

```
insert into mata_pljran values('10.01.001', 'matematika', '10', 'ganjil', '70'), ('10.01.002', 'bahasa indonesia', '10', 'ganjil', '80'), ('10.01.003', 'kewarganegaraan', '10', 'ganjil', '80'), ('10.01.004', 'agama', '10', 'ganjil', '80'), ('10.01.005', 'bahasa inggris', '10', 'ganjil', '65'), ('10.02.001', 'fisika', '10', 'genap', '65'), ('10.02.002', 'kimia', '10', 'genap', '70'), ('10.02.003', 'biologi', '10', 'genap', '70'), ('10.02.004', 'matematika', '10', 'genap', '70');
```

**Table nilai**

```
create table nilai( nis char(4), kd_mp char(10) , nk decimal(5,2), nuh decimal(5,2), nuts decimal(5,2), nuas decimal(5,2), akhir decimal(5,2) default null, primary key (nis,kd_mp), foreign key (nis) references siswa(nis) on update cascade on delete cascade, foreign key (kd_mp) references mata_pljran(kd_mp) on update cascade on delete cascade ); update nilai set akhir=nk*(0.15)+nuh*(0.15)+nuts*(0.3)+nuas*(0.4);
```

**Insert into table nilai**

```
INSERT INTO `nilai` (`nis`, `kd_mp`, `nk`, `nuh`, `nuts`, `nuas`) VALUES ('0001', '10.01.001', '80.00', '75.00', '85.00', '90.00'), ('0001', '10.01.002', '85.00', '85.00', '85.00', '85.00'), ('0001', '10.01.003', '75.00', '90.00', '85.00', '85.00'), ('0001', '10.01.004', '90.00', '65.00', '85.00', '85.00'), ('0001', '10.01.005', '95.00', '55.00', '85.00', '85.00'), ('0002', '10.01.001', '65.00', '68.00', '85.00', '85.00'), ('0002', '10.01.002', '80.00', '78.00', '85.00', '85.00'), ('0002', '10.01.003', '95.00', '100.00', '85.00', '85.00'), ('0002', '10.01.004', '85.00', '98.00', '85.00', '95.00'), ('0003', '10.01.001', '90.00', '68.00', '85.00', '95.00'), ('0003', '10.01.002', '85.00', '76.00', '35.00', '68.00'), ('0003', '10.01.003', '45.00', '87.00', '20.00', '45.00'), ('0003', '10.01.004', '35.00', '65.00', '85.00', '75.00'), ('0003', '10.01.005', '85.00', '95.00', '85.00', '85.00'), ('0005', '10.01.001', '90.00', '65.00', '85.00', '90.00'), ('0005', '10.01.002', '85.00', '78.00', '85.00', '90.00'), ('0005', '10.01.003', '95.00', '98.00', '85.00', '90.00'), ('0005', '10.01.004', '85.00', '58.00', '85.00', '75.00');
```

**Display final value(na):**

```
select s.nis, nama, m.kd_mp, nm_mp, kkm, (akhir) as na,
if (akhir <kkm,'GAGAL','TUNTAS') as ket from siswa s, mata_pljran m, nilai n where
s.nis=n.nis and m.kd_mp=n.kd_mp;
```

**RESULT:**

```
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+
| nis  | nama    | kd_mp     | nm_mp            | kkm  | na      | ket    |
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+
| 0001 | budi    | 10.01.001 | matematika       |   70 | 84.7500 | TUNTAS |
| 0002 | joko    | 10.01.001 | matematika       |   70 | 79.4500 | TUNTAS |
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.001 | matematika       |   70 | 87.2000 | TUNTAS |
| 0005 | marta   | 10.01.001 | matematika       |   70 | 84.7500 | TUNTAS |
| 0001 | budi    | 10.01.002 | bahasa indonesia |   80 | 85.0000 | TUNTAS |
| 0002 | joko    | 10.01.002 | bahasa indonesia |   80 | 83.2000 | TUNTAS |
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.002 | bahasa indonesia |   80 | 61.8500 | GAGAL  |
| 0005 | marta   | 10.01.002 | bahasa indonesia |   80 | 85.9500 | TUNTAS |
| 0001 | budi    | 10.01.003 | kewarganegaraan  |   80 | 84.2500 | TUNTAS |
| 0002 | joko    | 10.01.003 | kewarganegaraan  |   80 | 88.7500 | TUNTAS |
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.003 | kewarganegaraan  |   80 | 43.8000 | GAGAL  |
| 0005 | marta   | 10.01.003 | kewarganegaraan  |   80 | 90.4500 | TUNTAS |
| 0001 | budi    | 10.01.004 | agama            |   80 | 82.7500 | TUNTAS |
| 0002 | joko    | 10.01.004 | agama            |   80 | 90.9500 | TUNTAS |
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.004 | agama            |   80 | 70.5000 | GAGAL  |
| 0005 | marta   | 10.01.004 | agama            |   80 | 76.9500 | GAGAL  |
| 0001 | budi    | 10.01.005 | bahasa inggris   |   65 | 82.0000 | TUNTAS |
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.005 | bahasa inggris   |   65 | 86.5000 | TUNTAS |
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+
```

I would to display **max(na)** or **max(akhir)** for nm_mp=matematika and bahasa inggris **like this**

```
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+
| nis  | nama    | kd_mp     | nm_mp            | kkm  | na      | ket    |
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.001 | matematika       |   70 | 87.2000 | TUNTAS |
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.005 | bahasa inggris   |   65 | 86.5000 | TUNTAS |
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+
```

**How can I do that in mySQL ? Many thanks!**

i made it from cmd, sorry for my bad english

**EDIT**:
FINISHED by me ^_^ :

```
select s.nis, nama, m.kd_mp, nm_mp, kkm, (akhir) as na,
if (akhir <kkm,'GAGAL','TUNTAS') as ket from siswa s, mata_pljran m, nilai n where
akhir=(select max(akhir)
from nilai as a where a.kd_mp=n.kd_mp
having nm_mp in('bahasa inggris' , 'matematika')) and
s.nis=n.nis and m.kd_mp=n.kd_mp;
```

and ther result:

```
+------+---------+-----------+----------------+------+-------+--------+
| nis  | nama    | kd_mp     | nm_mp          | kkm  | na    | ket    |
+------+---------+-----------+----------------+------+-------+--------+
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.001 | matematika     |   70 | 87.20 | TUNTAS |
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.005 | bahasa inggris |   65 | 86.50 | TUNTAS |
+------+---------+-----------+----------------+------+-------+--------+
```

thanks :D

Comment: what did you try ? .. and what result would you expect for `nm_mb=agama`  ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to S.O. please post what hav you tried so far in order to help you to solve the problem. (S.O. its not private-free-online-homework-makers) thanks.

Comment: @JaMaBing using google traductor `akhir` means `end` its Indonesian.

Now the question is, the `end`of what ?

Comment: sorry, i have edit it, i mean max(na) for matematika and bahasa inggris

Comment: SO you want max 1 result from both category combined or want max from each category ?

Comment: @Melon this is not homework

Comment: @ErrHunter i want max from each category

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought(hadn't tried practically)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME having max(na) = na GROUP BY nm_mp
```

If it works or doesn't work, do tell me.
Its for all category.

For just that two category, try this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE nm_mp IN('matematika', 'bahasa inggris') having max(na) = na GROUP BY nm_mp
```

Comment: the result is Empity Set</br>
</br>

i use this coding:<br>
`select s.nis, nama, m.kd_mp, nm_mp, kkm, akhir as na,
if (akhir <kkm,'GAGAL','TUNTAS') as ket from siswa s, mata_pljran m, nilai n where
s.nis=n.nis and m.kd_mp=n.kd_mp and nm_mp in('matematika', 'bahasa inggris') 
 GROUP BY nm_mp having max(akhir) = akhir;`

Comment: Try putting Group by at end,
and do give alias to each table and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 SELECT NIS, NAMA, KD_MP, NM_MP, KKM, MAX(NA), KET
 FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE NM_MP = 'matematika'
 OR NM_MP = 'bahasa inggris'
 GROUP BY NM_MP
```

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: the result is  Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: NM_MP can only be 'matematika' or 'bahasa inggris'. so your query will always deliver an empty set

Comment: i have try this method <br/>
but the result is <br/>

    `+------+------+-----------+----------------+------+-------+--------+

| nis  | nama | kd_mp     | nm_mp          | kkm  | na    | ket    |
    +------+------+-----------+----------------+------+-------+--------+
    | 0001 | budi | 10.01.005 | bahasa inggris |   65 | 84.75 | TUNTAS |
    | 0001 | budi | 10.01.001 | matematika     |   70 | 84.75 | TUNTAS |
    +------+------+-----------+----------------+------+-------+--------+`

Comment: budi is not max value of matematika and bahasa inggris, the result would to display like this:<br/>
`
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+
| nis  | nama    | kd_mp     | nm_mp            | kkm  | na      | ket    |
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.001 | matematika       |   70 | 87.2000 | TUNTAS |
| 0003 | santoso | 10.01.005 | bahasa inggris   |   65 | 86.5000 | TUNTAS |
+------+---------+-----------+------------------+------+---------+--------+`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you need to do it old-school using a Correlated Subquery:

```
select *
from tab as t1
where nm_mp in ('matematika', 'bahasa inggris')
  and na = (select max(na) 
            from tab as t2
            where t1.nm_mp = t2.nm_mp)
```

or a Derived Table

```
select t1.*
from tab as t1 join
   (select nm_mp_, max(na) as max_na 
    from tab as t2
    where nm_mp in ('matematika', 'bahasa inggris')
    group by nm_mp
   ) as t2
on t1.nm_mp = t2.nm_mp
and t1.na = t2.max_na
```